# Как переделать на функции?

Tags: php, классы, pdo

Здравствуйте. Имеется вот такой вот user class, для авторизации, регистрации и проверки авторизован ли узверь.
Мне нужно переделать класс в функции, то есть вызывать их как функции а не обьекты класса. Как это можно вырезать и собрать правильно?

```
class Account {

private $account_data = [];

public function __construct() {

    global $db;

    if(isset($_COOKIE['account_session'])) {

        $account_session = unserialize($_COOKIE['account_session']);

        if(isset($account_session['account_id']) && $account_session['token']) {
            $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `id` = :id AND `token` = :token');
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $account_session['account_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':token', $account_session['token'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();

            if($stmt->rowCount()) {
                $this->account_data = $stmt->fetch();
            } else {
                setcookie('account_session', null, 1, '/');
            }
        } else {
            setcookie('account_session', null, 1, '/');
        }
    }
}

public function Auth() {
    return isset($this->account_data['id']);
}

public function getData($id = 0) {

    global $db;

    if($id && $id != @$this->account_data['id']) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `id` = :id');
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch();
    } else {
        return $this->account_data;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: а зачем это вам?

Comment: Я не умею пока что работать с классами, пишу на процедурке.

Comment: в классах те же функции с переменными, что и в процедурке, только называются они не много иначе. Изучайте параллельно и ООП, поверьте мне - без него сейчас работу вы не найдёте.

Answer (score 0):

Крайне сомнительная просьба. На мой взгляд, если вам предоставилась возможность поработать с классами, нужно учить =)

Но вот ваш ответ (старался сохранить стиль, в котором написан ваш вопрос):

```
    <?php


    $db = ''; // you database

    // init data
    $account_data = init($db); // init global account_data

    // get data
    $id = 0;
    $getData = getData($id, $account_data);

    //check fo auth
    $auth = auth($account_data);

    function init($db)
    {
        if (!isset($_COOKIE['account_session'])) {
            return null;
        }

        $account_session = unserialize($_COOKIE['account_session']);

        if (isset($account_session['account_id']) && $account_session['token']) {
            $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `id` = :id AND `token` = :token');
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $account_session['account_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':token', $account_session['token'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
                return $stmt->fetch();
            }
            setcookie('account_session', null, 1, '/');
            return null;
        }
        setcookie('account_session', null, 1, '/');
        return null;
    }

    function auth($account_data)
    {
        return isset($account_data['id']);
    }

    function getData($id = 0, $account_data)
    {
        if ($id && $id != @$account_data['id']) {
            $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `id` = :id');
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->fetch();
        }
        return $account_data;
    }
```